# SSL not working with custom domain through Heroku and PointDNS

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns

Currently hosting a PHP site on Heroku with a custom domain site that I bought through Hostgator. I've followed this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47930979/4470851 to get PointDNS set up for my custom domain, and this guide https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains to get the DNS Targets- I've set the given DNS targets as the CNAME alias through Hostgator, and now the custom domain is working, but I'm getting the insecure site warning through Chrome. I upgraded my Heroku Dyno to be a Hobby plan (per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management) so Heroku should be handling my SSL now. I'm getting the Firefox warning: "The certificate is only valid for the following names: *.herokuapp.com, herokuapp.com ".

This is not for a subdomain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got this working- for anyone else in the same boat, I had to also apply the DNS targets Heroku provided into the CNAME and ALIAS sections in PointDNS (they were set as .herokuapp.com addresses).

Comment: Could you show a picture like you did? I have the same problem!

Comment: @GuilhermeLirio Hopefully this helps-- https://i.imgur.com/qYKLDQK.jpg 

This is from in the PointDNS add-on